# How do I disable MSVC C2312 (multiple catch clauses for same type)?

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++

In a `VERIFY_THROWS()` macro, I have three catch blocks:

- for the exception type passed as an argument to the macro
- for `std::exception`, to report that an unexpected exception is caught and print `what()`
- for `...`, to report than an unknown exception was caught and re-throw

In code:

```
#define VERIFY_THROWS(E, ...) do { \
   try { __VA_ARGS__; /* log failure if control reaches here */ } \
   catch (const E &) { /* success */ } \
   catch (const std::exception &e) { /* log e.what(), failure */ } \
   catch (...) { /* log "unknown exception", failure */ }
} while (false)
```

Now, if I call `VERIFY_THROWS(std::exception, throw std::exception());`, the first and second catch block are for the same type and I get a `-Wexceptions` from GCC, which I can suppress with `_Pragma`, but from MSVC, I get a hard error C2312: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2312

An older version of the macro used nested try blocks to avoid this, but I find that not very elegant (do nested try blocks have more overhead in executable size, btw?).

Is there a better way? Just disabling the error like I did with the GCC warning won't work, will it?

Comment: What's wrong with nested try blocks if it's already hidden behind macro? Why care about executable size in what's presumably debug code?

Comment: @Osyotr: many a mickle makes a muckle.

Comment: Is there anyway you can edit your post with a plain text definition of your macro and example usage?  See also [mcve].